# Visual Studio 2012 Error "Does not contain a definition"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Visual Studio 2012 and C# in general. I created a simple Windows Forms Application project with just a few labels and textboxes. I then decided to change the name of the .cs file of my application from Form1.cs to Application.cs. Now there are 3 errors on the code-generated part in the Program.cs:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Application());
```

It says that my Application does not contain a definition for any of these methods. I have not changed anything except refactored the file names. What am i missing here?

Comment: When you renamed the file you got a messagebox: "You are renaming a file.  Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references to the code element 'Form1'?  Unfortunately you clicked Yes.  So now you have a class named "Application".  Which doesn't have an EnableVisualStyles method, etc.  Probably too late to press Ctrl+Z, good thing you use source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably referencing the wrong `Application` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application(v=vs.110).aspx

Use a different class name that doesn't clash or use a fully-qualified name with namespaces to disambiguate, i.e.:

```
MyProgram.AnotherNamespace.Application
System.Windows.Forms.Application
```

Comment: Thank you. I just found this out just a couple minutes ago. Because I renamed my .cs file into Application, Visual Studio Referenced that instead of referencing the original Application Class. Silly mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you changed your Form1.cs class to Application.cs, you overwrote the default Application class, which is built into the .NET libraries. When trying to access the class using

```
Application.Run();
```

it believes you are actually trying to call the method "Run" in your defined class and not the original .NET class.

The only/best way to fix this issue is assign the created class a different name to something that does not already exist. It is the best standard to give new classes a name that is not already being used.